# How can i print a JavaScript result in Currency format and also 2 decimal poinst

Tags: javascript, currency-formatting

Please am trying to get the result of this JavaScript in currency format, i have tried using .toFixed and Intl.NumberFormat('en-US' but didnt work.

**JS Fiddle Link**
https://jsfiddle.net/dh8n05L1/1/

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let abtc;
let bbtc;
let cbtc;
function btcvalue() {
    bbtc = $("#btc").val()
    $("#btcusdt").val(abtc * bbtc)
}
function btcusdtvalue() {
    cbtc = $("#btcusdt").val()
    $("#btc").val(cbtc / abtc)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get({
        url: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USDT",
        success: function(result) {
            
            abtc = result.USDT;
            btcvalue();
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("error")
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="asset" type="text" id="btc" step=".01" name="btc" onkeyup="btcvalue()" value="3" readonly>
                                   
 <input type="text" class="equiv" value="btcusdtvalue()" id="btcusdt" readonly>
 
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`
```

Comment: let number = number.toFixed(2);  it will give 2 number after decimal

Comment: let abtc;
let bbtc;
let cbtc; you define it but assign nothing to him on this line$("#btcusdt").val(abtc * bbtc) its multiplying with each other